# item for item in list & for item in list

Tags: python

Hi guys I need help with my function:

```
def stick(*args):

    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg,str):
             x="#".join(args)
             
             return x

        else:
             pass


print(stick("A","B","C"))
print(stick(2, 'time', 1, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
```

When I run it my interpreter give me erros:sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

So I try another code:

```
def stick(*args):
      args = [arg for arg in args if isinstance(arg, str)]
      result = '#'.join(args)
      
      return result

       
print(stick('sport', 'summer'))
print(stick(3, 5, 7))
print(stick(False, 'time', True, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
```

and this code compile with none errors but my main question is what is difference with my first function and my second function how write first function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.join` expects a collection of strings. The problem is here `"#".join(args)` You are not always having a collection of strings, so you can make sure to have strings before calling `str.join`

```
# if you want to append only when all elements are strings
def stick(*args):
    if  all(isinstance(arg, str) for arg in args):
        return "#".join(str(e) for e in args)


print(stick("A","B","C"))
print(stick(2, 'time', 1, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
print(stick(False, 'time', True, 'workout', [], 'gym'))


# if you want to append all elements that are strings.
def stick(*args):
    return "#".join(str(e) for e in args if isinstance(e, str))


print(stick("A","B","C"))
print(stick(2, 'time', 1, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
print(stick(False, 'time', True, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
```

**Outputs:**

Concatenating only when all are strings:

```py
A#B#C
None
None
```

Concatenating only the string elements:

```py
A#B#C
time#workout#gym
time#workout#gym
```

Comment: Did you mean: `return "#".join(str(e) for e in args)`?

Comment: @quamrana, I will updated my answer to make sure to only convert when all are strings.

Comment: I am not totally sure what you want, do you want to convert when all are strings or just the elements that are strings?

Comment: Now with the addition of `all(...)` the second line reduces to: `return "#".join(args)`

Comment: @quamrana, but you need all the elements in `args` to be type string to apply it. Otherwise, you will get an errors that you cannot concatenate elements that are not of string type.

Comment: But you've just checked that they are indeed *all* strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234829/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 2):

In your first code, you are using entire args to join with # tag but it contains non-str also. So, join will be raised an error.

So, I think you only want to join strings with # tag. So you code can be modified as follows,

```
def stick(*args):

    arr = []
    for arg in args:
        if  type(arg) == str:
            arr.append(arg)
        else:
            pass
      
    return '#'.join(arr)


print(stick("A","B","C"))
print(stick(2, 'time', 1, 'workout', [], 'gym'))
```

Output

```
A#B#C
time#workout#gym
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first function you have this line: `x="#".join(args)`

This simply iterates over items in `args` trying to create a string with `'#'` between each element.

This fails when *any* of the items is not a string already.

(Also note that when none of the arguments are strings it will not fail, but just return `None`)

Your second function only includes those elements which are already strings, so, for example, the test case: `print(stick(3, 5, 7))` prints an empty string.

Also your second function can be reduced to:

```py
def stick(*args):
    return '#'.join(arg for arg in args if isinstance(arg, str))
```

Comment: you don't actually need `[` and `]`.